# Python ctypes: Passing an array of strings

Tags: python, c, arrays, string, ctypes

I have an array of strings in Python 2.7, which I would like to pass to a C function via `ctypes`:

```
unsigned int SetParams(unsigned int count, const char **params)
```

So I can define the parameters in python:

```
import ctypes as ct
lib = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary('...')
lib.SetParams.restype  = ct.c_uint
lib.SetParams.argtypes = [ct.c_uint, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char_p)]
```

but now when I am given a set of params in a Python function, which I would like to use in the above library call, how do I actually call it? I am thinking something like this:

```
def setParameters(strParamList):
    numParams    = len(strParamList)
    strArrayType = ct.c_char_p * numParams
    strArray     = strArrayType()
    for i, param in enumerate(strParamList):
        strArray[i] = param
    lib.SetParams(numParams, strArray)
```

I am just starting with `ctypes` and wondering if there is a more automated way to do this? Also is the assignment `strArray[i] = param` actually reallocating? If so, this seems quite expensive -- is there a way to do this just pointing the string pointers to Python-allocated buffers, or they are not NULL-terminated?

**UPDATE** I did look through a couple related questions, but could not find a direct one to deal with the same issues. Thank you very much

Comment: For 'more automated' you might want to take a look at Cython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think correctly.  That code works.  Call with, for example:

```
setParameters(['abc','def','ghi'])
```

I haven't looked at the source, but `ctypes` on Python 2.7 (32-bit) does pass the internal Python buffer (tested by modifying the passed string in the C function and printing it after the call in Python), which is why you should only pass Python strings as above to functions that take `const char*` or at least are known not to modify the string.  Since Python strings are immutable writing to them under C is a no-no.  Use `ctypes.create_string_buffer` to create a writable string to pass to non-const `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to make the following adjustments to the `for` loop in the `setParameters` python function

```
for i, param in enumerate(strParamList):
   if isinstance(param, bytes):
      strArray[i] = c_char_p(param)
   else:
      strArray[i] = c_char_p(param.encode('utf-8'))
```

This worked if the array argument to `setParameters` was `[b'abc', b'def']` or `['abc','def']`.